# DKIM seems to be working but I get " dkim=temperror (no key for signature) "

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dkim

DKIM with Postfix on Ubuntu 20.04

part of the e-mail header as it arrives at my google mail account:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com header.s=smtpmail header.b=MdGUxaPe;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com designates 147.182.132.193 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=rapidseohost.com
Return-Path: <root@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com>
Received: from smtpmail.rapidseohost.com (smtpmail.rapidseohost.com. [147.182.132.193])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k13si244481qvc.109.2021.06.23.15.53.37
        for <michael.rajhel@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Wed, 23 Jun 2021 15:53:37 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com designates 147.182.132.193 as permitted sender) client-ip=147.182.132.193;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com header.s=smtpmail header.b=MdGUxaPe;
       spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com designates 147.182.132.193 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=root@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=rapidseohost.com
Received: by smtpmail.rapidseohost.com (Postfix, from userid 0) id 4ED14FC3C0; Wed, 23 Jun 2021 22:53:37 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=smtpmail.rapidseohost.com; s=smtpmail; t=1624488817; bh=WBggpZrfs7F0OzQkyE7LiZPHyfFFhl7N4CNav2f5YVw=; h=Subject:To:Date:From:From; b=MdGUxaPeNiXZrtSo91A2YQ/jZJPIAM6O9y+BBSS1vE51CIyZAR294V5Xpv2L3inK+
     66ocOYtKX27jE215AP5O71pHyCvy6HFC8bIDZ7s2MMAFlhywdQYXxvtAZ5hsbwllrA
     BHvG6gof1Ev33c8mLlArlt7Xcm3ra2oaAU6txHGk=
```

I thought it was a subdomain issue so I tried two different selector records.
I have DKIM TXT records in my DNS for both:

- `smtpmail._domainkey.rapidseohost.com`
- `smtpmail._domainkey.smtp.rapidseohost.com`

Both have the same DKIM value.

I also have a DKIM record for gmail suite with google selector which works just fine:

- `google._domainkey.rapidseohost.com`

Would appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Return-Path:` header references your sending envelope address ending in `@smtpmail.rapidseohost.com` and your host is called `smtpmail.rapidseohost.com`, that is different form `smtp.rapidseohost.com`.

Change the sending address, or add the records for that subdomain.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for your help!